# Adding suffix after 80 column using regular expression

Tags: perl, sed, awk, notepad++, gawk

I want to add a string and line number after column 80 in a program. I can use greedy match `(.*)` to match everything in a line and replace it with `\1  suffix` If I only have to add suffix. But how do I fill blanks/spaces up to column 80 then add `string` and then line number `#`. When I use `sed  -e "s/\(.*\)/\1  string/g" infile > outfile`. I am only able to add suffix but not after column 80 and with no line number. I am using sed, gawk available on windows via unxutil. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Why would you use regex for this?

Comment: I assume you meant end of line when you said 80 characters.

Comment: @MISHIK what are the other options?

Comment: How do you want to handle lines with over 80 characters?

Comment: @AdrianHHH Either there shall not be any line having characters more than 80  or  Such lines shall not be code line but comment line. If there are lines having more than 80 chars then such lines can either be broken and suffix and line number inserted at column 80 or suffix and line number added at the end. Both shall be acceptable.

Comment: Show a sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
perl -ple's{\A(.*)\z}{$1.(" "x(80-length($1)))." # $."}ex'
```

**Update:**

Adding some options.

```
Usage: script.pl [-start=1] [-end=0] [-pos=80] [-count=1] <file> ...
```

`script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# --------------------------------------
# Pragmatics

use v5.8.0;

use strict;
use warnings;

# --------------------------------------
# Modules

# Standard modules
use Getopt::Long;

use Data::Dumper;

# Make Data::Dumper pretty
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;

# Set maximum depth for Data::Dumper, zero means unlimited
local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 0;

# --------------------------------------
# Configuration Parameters

# Command line arguments
my %Cmd_options = (
  count =>  1,  # where to start the line counting
  end   =>  0,  # line to end on, zero means to end of file
  pos   => 80,  # where to place the line number
  start =>  1,  # which line to start on
);
my %Get_options = (
  'count=i' => \$Cmd_options{ count },
  'end=i'   => \$Cmd_options{ end   },
  'pos=i'   => \$Cmd_options{ pos   },
  'start=i' => \$Cmd_options{ start },
);

# conditional compile DEBUGging statements
# See http://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2013/07/a-look-at-conditional-compiling-of.html
use constant DEBUG => $ENV{DEBUG};

# --------------------------------------
# Variables

# --------------------------------------
# Subroutines

# --------------------------------------
#       Name: get_cmd_opts
#      Usage: get_cmd_opts();
#    Purpose: Process the command-line switches.
#    Returns: none
# Parameters: none
#
sub get_cmd_opts {

  # Check command-line options
  unless( GetOptions(
    %Get_options,
  )){
    die "usage: number_lines [<options>] [<file>] ...\n";
  }
  print Dumper \%Cmd_options if DEBUG;

  return;
}

# --------------------------------------
# Main

get_cmd_opts();

while( my $line = <> ){

  # is the line within the range?
  if( $. >= $Cmd_options{start} && $Cmd_options{end} && $. <= $Cmd_options{end} ){
    chomp $line;
    my $len = length( $line );
    printf "%s%s # %05d\n", $line, q{ } x ( $Cmd_options{pos} - $len ), $Cmd_options{count};
    $Cmd_options{count} ++;

  # else, just print the line
  }else{
    print $line;

  } # end if range
} # end while <>
```

Comment: It does the work. I am sorry to add additional thing but would you please explain what changes I shall need to make if I need to process only limited numbers of line in the file, say, 1003 to 2034. That is the script add `suffix` and line number 1 to 1031 in lines 1003 to 2034 of the file. Can I also fix  no of digits in the line number like 00001 instead of 1. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please guide me If I need to ask separate question for processing only limited number of lines. Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need something more complicated than a one liner. See above edits.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$0=$0"suffix"NR}1' your_file
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/$/suffix$./g' your_file
```

***Note: I assume you meant end of line when you said 80 characters***

Comment: 1st option adds suffix at beginning `suffix 1816OD(ICASE,3).EQ.0) THEN
suffix 1817D NO`. Second one adds both at beginning and end of line. `suffix1840C      CT=0.0suffix1841
suffix1841C      RT=0.0suffix1842
suffix1842C      RETURNsuffix1843`. both are not doing FROM COLUMN 80.

Comment: @sincere...Show your sample file!

Answer (score 0):

Code for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed ':a s/^.\{1,79\}$/& /;ta;s/$/& suffix/;=' file|sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/'
```

Comment: @captha. It does not add the line number.

Comment: @sincerenice yes you are completely right: I forgot the line numbers :( and therefore I added this now :)

Comment: @captha It works fine. Can you explain what all is happening? (I mostly use s///g loke commands in sed).